# mod_rewrite check if file exists in variant

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration

is there a way to check if the requested file is available as a local variant?

```
/project/config.php -> /project/config.local.php
```

I want to use this to switch between operating and testing system configuration.
Filenames matching *.local.* will be ignored in git. I'm not that familiar with the apache rewrite-engine. Thanks in advance for any idea.

### Solution 1

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.local\.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.([^./]+)$ /$1.local.$2 [L]
```

### Solution 2

Solution 1 works fine for the root directory but how should the .htaccess/httpd.conf be adapted to work in a `<Directory>` and `Alias` environment like:

```
Alias /projects "P:/projects/"
<Directory "P:/projects">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For me the following rule and conditions seem to work:

```
Alias /projects "P:/projects/"
<Directory "P:/projects">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /projects/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/([\w\.]+)\.(\w+)$
    RewriteCond %1/%2\.local\.%3 -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/([\w\.]+)\.(\w+)$

    RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2.local.%3 [L]
</Directory>
```

I'm not really sure if this is the most efficient way due to four different conditions. In this case it would be nice to have a `REQUEST_URI_BASE` var which does contain `REQUEST_URI`without the filename.

Comment: Which folder is your htaccess located (root or `project` folder) ? Is this rule only to be applied on files in `/project/` folder ? Also, is this rule only to be applied on `config.php` or other files in `/project/` folder ?

Comment: This rule will be applied in the root-folder and it should handle all file requests. Before returning \*.\* the server should check if a file named \*.local.\* is available and to return this instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in your document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.local\.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.([^./]+)$ /$1.local.$2 [L]
```

This code checks if requested URI is an existing file.
If so, it then checks if its `local` version exists.
If so, then it internally rewrites to `local` version instead of serving `normal` version.

---

EDIT: in apache config file directly (since it's *out of* document root, and stored on another drive, it's a bit harder but here's a solution).

We can't use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` anymore in that case

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^([^/]+)(.+)\.([^./]+)$
RewriteCond %1%2\.local\.%3 -f
RewriteRule ^ %2.local.%3 [L]
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.
How should the .htaccess be adapted to work in a <Directory> environment?

Comment: You mean you want to put this code in your apache configuration file directly, without using an htaccess ?

Comment: Your solution works within a .htaccess file in the DocumentRoot-directory (eg. `DocumentRoot "R:/htdocs"`). But when i use this .htaccess in an alias directory (`Alias /projects "P:/projects/"`
`<Directory "P:/projects">...</Directory>` the RewriteCond are not matching.

Comment: I reproduced the environment you described and came to a solution (you can see my edited answer)